# Setting up Git before pushing my project live

Tags: github, symfony-1.4, web-deployment, production

I am making a small web project which I am doing on the LAMP stack using the Symfony 1.4 MVC framework. I am interested in documenting everything, right from the database to the code and I want to push all my code onto GitHub. I know how to setup a repository on GitHub and push changes etc live.

What I am unable to wrap around my head is this:

I have the development server, which after testing it out I push it onto my GitHub repository, after this I want to naturally have to push it onto my production server. Typically, this being a one man project, I can easily push the project live to my production server using rsync. And this is how I would typically configure it in my YAML files and then symfony will automatically push the changes to my production server.

Naturally, I want GitHub as the intermediary where the code to my project is saved and from there I should be able to deploy it to my production server.

But how exactly I should achieve this, I have no clue.

Can anybody suggest the missing pieces to this puzzle?

Comment: If I understand your queestion correctly you would like to deploy your code to production right from a github (or any other git) repository? There is a tool called [Capifony](http://capifony.org/), which can do it for you. It's a ruby tool, but easy to learn and works grate.

Comment: yea, isn't that how everyone else does it? By saying it's a ruby tool do you mean it's developed in Ruby ?

Comment: Yes, it's written in ruby. It's actually a wrapper around capistrano which originally was developed to deploy rails apps. I use capifony during my work to deploy symfony projects, but with a private git server. It works realy well for us. An another widespread deploy tool is [fabric](http://fabfile.org).

Comment: cool, thanks for the suggestions, I am going to roll ahead with capifony coz of it's smooth integration with Symfony!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Capifony](http://capifony.org/) to deploy your symfony project.